# Uninstall rails 3.2.8 in ubuntu 11.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ubuntu-11.04

I need to downgrade from rails 3.2 to 3.0.. So I guess I might need to uninstall 3.2 first and then re-install 3.0.. I tried using sudo gem uninstall rails. But still if i type rails -v it is showing Rails3.2.8.. But when I go the location of rails application and then type rails -v it is showing

**"Could not find rails-3.2.8 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems."**

Please help me how do I downgrade it

Answer (score 0):

<s>I don't use Ruby on Rails so i'm not 100% sure about it, but how about doing it "Ubuntu-style"?</s>

```
$ sudo apt-get remove rails
```

**EDIT**: It seems like someone already answered this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12204468/1261527 :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually "downgrade" rails, you just install whichever version you need for a given project by putting that version into your Gemfile and then running `bundle`.

If that version already exists on your machine the bundle will just 'use' it in putting together your rails application.  If not, it will go out and get that specific version, install it on your machine and then use it for that project.

New versions are coming out all the time, so after a while most machines have several versions, and of course different developers might have different version so specifying it in the `Gemfile` is very useful.

Recently (one of the rails `3.2.x` versions) the ability to actually specify the Ruby version itself in the Gemfile was added.  I think it was a change to bundler itself.

To help manage the whole version thing, most folks like to use RVM (or rbenv, an alternative) to manage all the versions more recently.

You can also just install a specific version with `gem install rails -vX.X.X`, then bundler will just use it (useful if bundle would be run offline say).

Finally your `rails -v` command is showing the current rails version on your machine - but that can, and frequently is, different from the version in a given project's Gemfile.

Comment: I tried using gem approach. I edited the rails version to 3.0.17 in the Gemfile and when I ran bundle install it is showing error message as "Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties": Is there anything I have to do??
  In Gemfile:
    coffee-rails (~> 3.2.1) ruby depends on
      railties (~> 3.2.0.beta) ruby

    rails (= 3.0.17) ruby depends on
      railties (3.0.17)
"

Comment: @user662503, could you add your Gemfile to your question?